# UITableView mixing up section items

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to open 2 different Viewcontrollers from the first 2 sections of my tableview and some URL's from the other 4 sections. The first section doesn't do anything and the others are mixing up, and the sections with which should open the URL's don't work. Thanks for your responses.

```
@implementation SettingsViewController {
NSArray * sectionheaderArr;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

sectionheaderArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"fb",  
nil),NSLocalizedString(@"recommend", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"feedback", 
nil),NSLocalizedString(@"rate", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"language", 
nil),NSLocalizedString(@"all_providers", nil), nil];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: 
(NSInteger)section{
return sectionheaderArr.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
int row = indexPath.row;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
cell.textLabel.text = [sectionheaderArr objectAtIndex:row];

return cell;
}



-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   
*)indexPath{
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    if (indexPath.row ==0){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openFacebook" sender:self];
    }
}
if (indexPath.section ==1) {
  if (indexPath.row ==1) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"opentest" sender:self];
  }
}

if (indexPath.section==2) {
    if (indexPath.row ==2) {
        UIApplication*app1 = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        NSString*path = @"http://www.google.de";
        NSURL*myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
        [app1 openURL:myurl];
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Looks like you only have 1 section in your UITableView? Try changing your numberOfSectionsInTableView:

Comment: I already tried that, didn't work..

Comment: Try doing this:
Change your didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: for didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and then remove all your if(indexPath.section ==). I mean, use only the inner "ifs"

Comment: I can mark it as answer if you type the solution  =)

Comment: Thank you. I've already copied it as an answer so you can check it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is the answer to your question:

```
@implementation SettingsViewController {
NSArray * sectionheaderArr;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

sectionheaderArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"fb",  
nil),NSLocalizedString(@"recommend", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"feedback", 
nil),NSLocalizedString(@"rate", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"language", 
nil),NSLocalizedString(@"all_providers", nil), nil];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: 
(NSInteger)section{
return sectionheaderArr.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
int row = indexPath.row;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
cell.textLabel.text = [sectionheaderArr objectAtIndex:row];

return cell;
}



-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   
*)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.row ==0){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openFacebook" sender:self];
    }


  if (indexPath.row ==1) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"opentest" sender:self];
  }



    if (indexPath.row ==2) {
        UIApplication*app1 = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        NSString*path = @"http://www.google.de";
        NSURL*myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
        [app1 openURL:myurl];
    }


}
```

Please note that I've also changed the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method as you were implementing "didDeselectRowAtIndexPath" so it won't work until you DEselect your cell.

Thanks also @iphonic for his explanation.

Comment: I want to have a rate button in my app, the link works fine on browser but from iphone simluator safari it says: URL not found. 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/woverkaufen/id595365151?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4"]];

Answer (score 0):

The datasource method for `UITableView`

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

is used to define number of sections for `UITableView`, and each section has different rows starts from 0,1,2.....

In your case you are trying with different `indexPath.section` where as it should use only `1 section`, and for multiple sections there should be multiple datasource for the sections to be defined.

As you already got the solution, I just want to clear the concept of `indexPaths` `rows and sections`.

Thanks.